# Error retrieving IAM policy GCP when terraform plan?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hello one of my modules for terraform bootstrap for GCP contains

```
  resource "google_organization_iam_member" "organizationAdmin" {
  for_each = toset(var.users)
  org_id   = var.organization_id
  role     = "roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin"
  member   = each.value

}
```

right now I'm getting

```
Error: Error retrieving IAM policy for organization "903021035085 ": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
│ 
│   with module.bootstrap_permissions.google_organization_iam_member.organizationAdmin["group:gcp-organization-admins@juliusoh.tech"],
│   on ../modules/bootstrap_permissions/main.tf line 1, in resource "google_organization_iam_member" "organizationAdmin":
│    1: resource "google_organization_iam_member" "organizationAdmin" {
```

The account making the request has Owner permission at the Organization level, is there a reason why I am getting an error, when I do terraform plan.

Comment: What are the values in **var.users**? The argument **member**  is formatted like this **user:someone@example.com**. Do you have the **user:** part in front of the user's email address?

Comment: module.bootstrap_permissions.google_organization_iam_member.organizationAdmin["group:gcp-organization-admins@juliusoh.tech"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `var.organization_id` has a trailing space (see the error message), e.g., `"123 "` instead of `"123"`. Remove this space and it should work.

Comment: Wow thank you, how did you catch that? crazy